# How do I instruct Applescript to open a new Firefox window with a link?

Tags: firefox, applescript

My code looks like this

```
tell application "Firefox"
 open location "http://rubyquicktips.tumblr.com/"
end tell
```

But if I have Firefox open, the link will open in a new tab. But I want the link to open in a new Firefox window.
How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this...

```
tell application "Firefox"
    OpenURL "http://rubyquicktips.tumblr.com/"
end tell
```

or try this...

```
tell application "Firefox" to activate
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "n" using command down
tell application "Firefox"
    OpenURL "http://rubyquicktips.tumblr.com/"
end tell
```

Comment: OpenURL doesn't work with Leopard...but your second tip is brilliant!

Comment: As for now, we're actually on Mac OS 10.12.5. This solution won't work anymore. If someone still want to do so, you should replace the OpenURL by open location, like blubb is mentionning in is answer.

Answer (score 12):

this works, but opens your welcome site in first tab...

```
tell application "Firefox" to activate
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "n" using command down
delay 3
tell application "Firefox"
    open location "http://rubyquicktips.tumblr.com/"
end tell
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not entirely familiar with AppleScript, but I was looking to open a brand new default window. Here's a method that works:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Firefox"
        click menu item "New Window" of menu "File" of menu bar 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Optionally, to focus on the new window, add these lines afterward:

```
tell application "Firefox"
    activate
end tell
```

This will open a default new window. There may be a better way.

Answer (score 4):

Note:

As of at least Firefox v50, you can make Firefox *default* to opening URLs in a new window, by unchecking `Open new windows in a new tab instead` on the `General` tab of Firefox's preferences.

Note, however, that this is a persistent setting that affects *all* URLs opened from outside of Firefox.

The solution below may still be of interest if you don't want to rely on the state of that setting.
(Unfortunately, due to Firefox's limited AppleScript support, there is no similarly robust solution for always opening in a *tab*, irrespective of the state of the setting).

---

Here's a more robust solution that:

- doesn't rely on a fixed delay and
- is language-neutral (as is the keystroke-sending approach); i.e., it also works with localized names for the menus and commands (e.g., "Datei" for "File", ...)

However, because GUI scripting is employed for programmatically clicking on a menu item, you do need to [authorize the *calling application*for assistive access first](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202802) (a one-time action that requires administrative privileges) - e.g., if your script is run from a terminal, you must authorize `Terminal.app`, but even `Script Editor.app` must be authorized if you want to run your script while developing it.

```applescript
tell application "Firefox"

    # Make Firefox frontmost.
    activate

    # Wait until it is truly frontmost.
    repeat while not frontmost
        delay 0.1
    end repeat

    # Open a new window using GUI scripting (requires authorization for assistive access),
    tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Firefox"
        set windowCountBefore to (count of windows)
        # Click on File > New to open a new window, but locate it
        # by keyboard shortcut rather than by name, so as to also work
        # with localized menu names.
        tell menu 1 of menu bar item 3 of menu bar 1
            click (first menu item whose value of attribute "AXMenuItemCmdChar" is "N" and value of attribute "AXMenuItemCmdModifiers" is 0)
        end tell
        # Wait for the new window to appear.
        repeat while (count of windows) = windowCountBefore
            delay 0.2
        end repeat
    end tell

    # Finally, open the URL.    
    open location "http://example.org/"

end tell
```

Note:

- Under normal circumstances, if Firefox is responsive, this should work reliably. However, the code could be improved by implementing timeouts for the waiting loops.
- Firefox isn't the fastest at opening the new window, so Firefox will first activate, and the new window will only appear about a second or so later.
- The new window will invariably have an empty first tab, and the URL will open in the *2nd* tab.

A side note re the unusual-looking `tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Firefox"` construct:

- The main block targets the Firefox *application* (`tell application "Firefox"`).
- However, GUI scripting must be done in the context of the `System Events` application (`tell application "System Events"`), and, within that context, it is the Firefox *process* that must be targeted (`tell application process "FireFox"`). While you could write *two nested* `tell` blocks, they're combined into a single block here for convenience and brevity.

Comment: @EdRandall: Yes, whatever application is executing the GUI scripting code must be authorized; I've added an explicit note re Script Editor. Re timeouts: Good idea, but the answer already states "the code could be improved by implementing timeouts for the waiting loops"; as an aside: it is not lack of authorization that  could cause these specific loops to get stuck (the 1st one doesn't require authorization, and the 2nd one would not be reached if authorization were lacking).

Answer (score 1):

solutions which "activate" are wrong because they switch desktop

```
do shell script "open -n -a Firefox"
```

Comment: RE: "solutions which "activate" are wrong because they switch desktop" -- Well that is not true if one is only using one, and only true if using more than one and the target app is not opened on the current one. Also, the OP wants to open a URL in that new window and as such your answer is incomplete.

Comment: have not found better alternative, for Safari I used "make new document", but with Big Sur update they made new window in Safari opening for 5 seconds (idk if they did it on purpose to make M1 macs feel faster)

Comment: The OP is talking about **Firefox**, so **Safari** has nothing to do with this! Your answer as written is factually inaccurate and incomplete of what the OP requests!

Answer (score 1):

I use the below simple `shell script` to `open` `multiple firefox pages in different tabs` and **`it works for me.`** May be you need to adjust the sleep time little bit.

### Steps:

1. Go to `Automator`
2. Select: `Application`
3. Click on `choose`
4. Search `Run Shell Script`
5. Click and drag it to the `right hand window`
6. In `Shell` select `/bin/bash`
7. In Pass input: `select as arguments`
8. `Paste` the below code

   > ```
   > #!/bin/bash
   >
   > open -a Firefox https://stackoverflow.com
   > sleep 0.5
   > open -a Firefox https://apple.com
   > sleep 0.5
   > open -a Firefox https://google.com
   > ```
9. `Command + S` to save it
10. Give a name and location to save.
11. Choose File format: `Application`
12. `Save`
13. `Add` it in your `dock` (applicable for MAC os) and `enjoy` (applicable for every os :)!!